# Complex Numbers C

Tags: java

Below I have my code for creating complex Number and I would to be able to call add or subtract or divide on the object without hardcoding it ,how may I go about doing that ?

```
  Scanner firstguess = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the real part:  ");
  double first = firstguess.nextDouble();

  Scanner secon = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the imaginary part:  ");
  double second = secon.nextDouble();

  Complex a = new Complex(num, denom);
  Complex b = new Complex(first, second);
  Scanner g = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the arithmetic you want done:  ");
  String choice = g.next();

  System.out.println(a.add(b));
```

Comment: creat add() , sub(), and divide() methods in the Complex class.

Comment: I have I want to know how to call them without having to hardcode the method I'm choosing

Comment: didn't get what are you trying to say by hard coding! ... you are not hard coding anything... just call the required method where you need it.

Comment: For example g is the scanner object if the user types in subtract or multiply I want to be able to call the specified method based on the users input.

Comment: So, do that: `if (userInput.equals("subtract")) { do the subtraction } else ...`.

Comment: A switch-case would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have I want to know how to call them without having to hardcode the method I'm choosing – Daniel

basically you cannot avoid that. Somehow you have to tell the computer what to do...

The better question is : how do you *select* the right method to call.

You have some options:

- if/else cascade
- switch
- generic *interface* and a map

Since only the last is heading toward OOP (while the others are *procedural approaches* I'll demonstrate that:

You define a custom *interface*:

```
interface ComplexOperation{
 Complex calculate(Complex c1, complex c2);
}
```

You define a *map* like this:

```
Map<String,ComplexOperation> operations = new HashMap<>();
```

then you put the operation signs in that map along with an *implementation* of your Interface:

```
operations.put("+",new AddOperation()); // form 1: top level or named inner class
operations.put("-",new ComplexOperation() { // form 2: anonymous inner class 
    @Override
    public Complex calculate(Complex c1, complex c2){
      return c1.subtract(c2);
    }
});
operations.put("*",(c1,c2) -> c1.multiply(c2)); // form 3: Java8 Lambda.
```

Form 1 needs an additional class:

```
class AddOperation implements ComplexOperation{
    @Override
    public Complex calculate(Complex c1, complex c2){
      return c1.add(c2);
    }
}
```

the you use it this way:

```
 System.out.println("Please enter the arithmetic you want done:  ");
  String choice = g.next();

  if(operations.containsKey(choice)){
    System.out.println(operations.get(choice).calculate(c1,c2));
  else
    System.err.println("invalid operation: "+choice);
```